# Failing to access target viewController

Tags: ios, swift

I want to have a blur effect on my targetController, i code for it in my view controller , as suggested by one expert @DonMag , **but the blur effect does not show** and **a button to close the view does not respond to click** , the images of what i have and what i want are below

[image]

[image]

My viewcontroller code

```
import UIKit

class RateMainViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var btnCollection: [UIButton] = []
    var bgImage = UIImageView()
    var crossBtn = UIButton()
    
    
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func commonInit() {
        
        let coolBtn = UIButton()
        coolBtn.setTitle("cool", for: .normal)
        coolBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "cool"), for: .normal)
        
        let sadBtn = UIButton()
        sadBtn.setTitle("sad", for: .normal)
        sadBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "sad"), for: .normal)
        
        let angryBtn = UIButton()
        angryBtn.setTitle("angry", for: .normal)
        angryBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"angry"), for: .normal)
        
        
        let loveBtn = UIButton()
        loveBtn.setTitle("love", for: .normal)
        loveBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"love"), for: .normal)
        
        let happyBtn = UIButton()
        happyBtn.setTitle("happy", for: .normal)
        happyBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"happy"), for: .normal)
        
        btnCollection.append(contentsOf: [happyBtn,coolBtn,loveBtn,sadBtn,angryBtn])
        
        let font = UIFont(name: "Rubik-Medium", size: 30)
        let fontM = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body)
        
        
        
        bgImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bgImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width).isActive = true
        bgImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.height).isActive = true
        
        bgImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        
        let animationBlur = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
        let visualBlur = UIVisualEffectView(effect: animationBlur)
        visualBlur.frame = bgImage.bounds
        
        addSubview(visualBlur)
        
        let stackMoji = UIStackView()
        
        stackMoji.axis = .vertical
        stackMoji.spacing = 10
        stackMoji.alignment = .top
        stackMoji.distribution = .fill
        stackMoji.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        
        btnCollection.forEach { (stackBtn) in
            stackMoji.addArrangedSubview(stackBtn)
            
            stackBtn.titleLabel?.font = fontM.scaledFont(for: font!)
        }
        
        bgImage.addSubview(stackMoji)
        
        crossBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "cross"), for: .normal)
        
        bgImage.addSubview(crossBtn)
        crossBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        crossBtn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgImage.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
        crossBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgImage.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
        
        
        
        
        
        stackMoji.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgImage.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        stackMoji.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgImage.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        
    }
    
}
```

The code of controller where i want all this to show up

```
import UIKit

class RateController: UIViewController {
    var restaurant: Restaurant!
    let rateViews = RateMainViewCell()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(rateViews.bgImage)
        view.addSubview(rateViews.crossBtn)
        
        if let restaurantImage = restaurant.image {
            
            rateViews.bgImage.image = UIImage(data: restaurantImage as Data)
            
        }
        
        
        
        rateViews.crossBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(closeRatings), for: .touchUpInside)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @objc func closeRatings() {
      
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    
    
    /*
     // MARK: - Navigation
     
     // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     }
     */
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        let backImage = UIImage(named: "back")
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = backImage
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImage
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
        
    }
    
}
```

UPDATE- code to come to ratecontroller

```
@objc func gotoRatings() {
        let rateDetailView = RateController()
      rateDetailView.restaurant = restaurant
        rateDetailView.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(rateDetailView, animated: true, completion: nil)
                     //     rateDetailView.restaurant = restaurant
                          
                          //navigationController?.pushViewController(rateDetailView, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: why would you add `UITableViewCell` as a subview to view? Why not simply inherit from `UIView`? also try to bring `visualBlur` to front using `bringSubViewToFront`

Comment: I tried bringing subviewtofront does not seem to help, converting to UIView does not seem to help as well

Comment: @multiverse - as with your other question, try to be more detailed about what you are trying to do. Your code references `navigationController` but your images don't show the use of a new controller. Do you want a blurred food image to cover everything? Or do you want a "blur effect" to cover what's current;y showing, and add your "face" buttons?

Comment: @DonMag, i am using navigationController but the back button is some how not showing, i want the backimage which is the added to background to be blurred, so that the emoji appear more bright and clear

Comment: @DonMag - i was using modal to present the view as in updated code above, so the navigation arrow was not visible, if i were to use push, then the arrow is visible, i am trying all possible ways but sowe how on controller the views are not showing up the way. they are in view class

Comment: @multiverse - please review [ask]. It's very difficult (and frustrating) for people to try and offer help when you don't fully describe what you're doing, and post code that is not the same as your images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you:

- have navigated to a VC in a navigation controller
- want to tap a button (or some other action) and present a stack of rating buttons
- want the background to be a dark, blurred image
- want it full-screen (so it covers the navigation bar)

First, your "X" button cannot be tapped because it's in the safe-area. It needs to be positioned with respect to that.

Second, your visual effects view is not showing because you didn't give it a frame.

Third, absolutely no idea why you would try to use a `UITableViewCell` subclass, as this is not a cell in a table view.

Fourth, your "rating" view (or view controller) should know as little as possible about anything else. Design your code so it can simply notify the "calling / presenting controller" that a button was selected. Let that controller decide what to do.

To accomplish the Fourth point, you can use a "callback closure." In your "rating" controller class, declare a variable:

```
var callback: ((Int) -> ())?
```

When you instantiate that controller, assign the `callback` like this:

```
    // instantiate rating controller
    let vc = MyRateViewController()

    // assign callback closure
    vc.callback = { idx in
        print("button in modal controller tapped:", idx)
        // do what you need to do with that information
    }
```

then, in your modal controller class, use something like this in your button action:

```
callback?(2)
```

---

Here is some example code:

```
class TestRateViewController: UIViewController {

    let ratings: [String] = [
        "happy",
        "cool",
        "love",
        "sad",
        "angry",
    ]
    
    let statLabel = UILabel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // for demonstration, add a button
        // when tapped, it will present MyRateViewController (full-screen)
        let b = UIButton()
        b.setTitle("Test Rate View Controller", for: [])
        b.backgroundColor = .red
        
        // add a label to show the result of the rating
        statLabel.textAlignment = .center
        statLabel.text = "Selected Rating:"
        
        b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        statLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(b)
        view.addSubview(statLabel)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            b.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            b.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 200.0),
            statLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            statLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: b.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
        ])
        
        b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.didTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
    }
    
    @objc func didTap(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        
        // instantiate rating controller
        let vc = MyRateViewController()
        
        // assign its .bgImage property
        if let img = UIImage(named: "food") {
            vc.bgImage = img
        }
        
        // assign its ratings string array
        vc.ratings = self.ratings
        
        // we want it to fill the screen?
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        
        // assign callback closure
        vc.callback = { idx in
            self.gotRating(idx)
        }
        
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
    
    func gotRating(_ idx: Int) -> Void {
        
        // if crossBtn was tapped
        if idx == -1 {
            statLabel.text = "Selected Rating: crossBtn tapped"
            // nothing to do
        } else {
            statLabel.text = "Selected Rating: \(idx) \(ratings[idx])"
            // code to save the selected rating
        }
        
        // dismiss the modal view controller
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
    
}

class MyRateViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // set by calling controller
    var bgImage: UIImage?
    var ratings: [String]?
    var callback: ((Int) -> ())?
    
    let stackMoji = UIStackView()
    let crossBtn = UIButton()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if ratings == nil {
            fatalError("Caller did not set ratings string array!")
        }
        
        // start with system font
        var font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .bold)

        // buttons use "Rubik-Medium" if available
        if let f = UIFont(name: "Rubik-Medium", size: 30) {
            font = f
        }
        let fontM = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body)
        
        // properties of stack view
        stackMoji.axis = .vertical
        stackMoji.alignment = .leading
        stackMoji.spacing = 10
        stackMoji.distribution = .fillEqually
        
        // create "moji" buttons, set properties, add to stack
        ratings?.forEach { title in
            let b = UIButton()
            b.setTitle(title, for: [])
            if let img = UIImage(named: title) {
                b.setImage(img, for: [])
            }
            b.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            b.titleLabel?.font = fontM.scaledFont(for: font)
            b.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            b.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .highlighted)
            // add target for each button
            b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            stackMoji.addArrangedSubview(b)
        }
        
        // create "cross" button
        if let img = UIImage(named: "cross") {
            crossBtn.setImage(img, for: .normal)
        } else {
            crossBtn.setTitle("X", for: [])
            crossBtn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            crossBtn.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .highlighted)
            crossBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 44, weight: .bold)
        }
        
        let bkgImageView = UIImageView()
        bkgImageView.backgroundColor = .blue
        bkgImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        
        if bgImage != nil {
            bkgImageView.image = bgImage
        }
        
        // create blur visual effect view
        let animationBlur = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
        let visualBlurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: animationBlur)
        
        
        // add elements to self
        view.addSubview(bkgImageView)
        view.addSubview(visualBlurView)
        view.addSubview(stackMoji)
        view.addSubview(crossBtn)
        
        [bkgImageView, visualBlurView, stackMoji, crossBtn].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain background image to all 4 sides
            bkgImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            bkgImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            bkgImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            bkgImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            
            // constrain visualBlurView to all 4 sides
            visualBlurView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            visualBlurView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            visualBlurView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            visualBlurView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            
            // constrain crossBtn to top / inset 16-pts from left (for aesthetics)
            crossBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            crossBtn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            
            // center the stack view
            stackMoji.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            stackMoji.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            
            // make stack view 60% of height of self ?
            stackMoji.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.6),
            
        ])
        
        // add target for crossBtn
        crossBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
    }
    
    @objc func btnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) -> Void {
        
        if sender == crossBtn {
            callback?(-1)
        } else {
            guard let idx = stackMoji.arrangedSubviews.firstIndex(of: sender) else {
                // shouldn't happen
                return
            }
            callback?(idx)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Set a `TestRateViewController` view controller in your navigation controller. It will look like this (iPhone 11):

[image]

When you tap the button, you'll get this:

[image]

After tapping an "emoji" button (or the X button), the modal controller will be dismissed and the "Selected Rating" label will be updated.

---

Note: I used a random food image for the background (named "food") and clipped your "emoji" images out of the image in your question (named "happy", "cool", "love", "sad", "angry").

Here are the images I used:

[image: food]

[image: happy][image: cool][image: love][image: sad][image: angry]

Comment: was not really able to explain , all i wanted was 1) The rating page opens on pressing a "rate this hotel button" via modal or push, when it opens, it shows the hotel image as bg but blurred spread across whole screen and with the emojis attached in front so they now look bright, i was not able to constraint the views of image and close button, i will now go through your detailed code , thanks